# Android: Getting the current date and time

Tags: android, date, calendar

I am trying to get the today's date and time using the following code,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

but the outcome is

26/15/2014 13:15 instead of 26/1/2014 13:15

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The date format is wrong.. (first occurrence of mm) pls refer to the Documentation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace first mm with MM. Check documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use M instead of m for the month. m means minutes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

replace dd/mm/yyyy

by dd/MM/yyyy

capital M for month
small   m for minute

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is wrong `"dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm"` it should be `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"`, Notice the **MM**

**Instead of `SimpleDateFormat` use `DateFormat`**

Because `SimpleDateFormat` is Depreciated though

```
android.text.format.DateFormat dateFormat= new android.text.format.DateFormat();
dateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new java.util.Date());
```

Comment: Downvoteres highly appreciated to explain the reason

Comment: In Api reference no where mentioned that SimpleDateFormat is depreciated. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Have you ever developed an app and used this? I have 11 Specific Projects which i was using THIS format, and i changed now to this

Comment: The reason behind this is SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe

Answer (score 0):

You should use right format

H   hours
m   minutes
s   seconds
S   fractions of Second
a   am/pm marker
d   day of the month
M   month of the year
y   year
w   week of year

```
 String[] formats = new String[] {
   "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
 };
 for (String format : formats) {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
   System.out.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
   System.out.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
 }
```

and the output is

```
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1969-12-31
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1970-01-01
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1969-12-31 16:00
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1970-01-01 00:00
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1969-12-31 16:00-0800
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1970-01-01 00:00+0000
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31 16:00:00.000-0800
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000+0000
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-0800
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000
```

**Which produces the above output when run in the America/Los_Angeles time zone:**

know more from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)