# Date in android is returning future date instead of current date

Tags: android, date

I am facing problem where I am extracting date from `Date class` in android and using it in my activity, But my problem here is everything works fine but date function returns `25/03/2014` instead of current date.

Now I am confused why it is returning this irrelavent date instead of current date, Also there is no error.

My code:

```
import java.util.date;

SimpleDateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
dateformat.format(new Date());
```

Please help to know how to get current date.

Comment: use dd/MM/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Getting the current date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360036/android-getting-the-current-date-and-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [SimpleDateFormat API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html),

> d day in month
>
> **m   minute in hour**
>
> **M   month in year**
>
> y year

Change `dd/mm/yyyy` to `dd/MM/yyyy` for day/month/year format.

Comment: @Siva when in doubt, check the API reference first.

Answer (score 1):

Use this dude

```
Date date = new Date(location.getTime());
    DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
   System.out.println("Time: " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Bhanu but from where are we getting `mTimeText`, I can't see any reference to this in the code you provided.

Comment: ohk just forgot this set text see my edited ans dude

Comment: ohk that was just for see the answer ohk now i put System.out.println instead of that

Comment: I am looking for current date @Bhanu but you gave `System.out.println("Time: "`.. Is this a typo error? but will a try of your code

Comment: DateFormat.format("hh:mmaa dd/MM/yyyy", System.currentTimeMillis());

Answer (score 1):

Please check `Time & Date` settings of your emulator, sometimes that causes the issues like those as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Super User will check the date and time of emulator.

Comment: @Siva you are welcome, that thing mentioned above often makes issues like that, but I think someone does not like my `answer`, he voted me down, why?

Comment: no idea @Super User but I am unable to check now but will check today about your advice

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I guess since the issue is clearly on the code itself, not the device setting, the downvoter saw this as not helpful.

Comment: @AndrewT. I agree but sometimes that could be helpful as well, isn't that right?

Comment: Well, I'm not the downvoter. I don't know why he downvoted it (hence, only my guessing). Looking at current score, people agreed that your answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is giving me correct time

```
  String ntime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response raj but I am trying to get date not time

Answer (score 0):

For Date u can use

```
 String ndate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
```